# How to inject a Spring bean into JpaRepositoryFactoryBean

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have my own custom Spring Data common repository in order to provide common behavior to all Spring Data repositories. And all I need is to modify EntityManager when repository is being created. But I can't inject a Spring bean into JpaRepositoryFactoryBean due to the bean is created via new operator.

```
public class BasicJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

 @Autowired
 private SomeService service; // - it does not work 

  @Override
  protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {
    // do some logic here
    service.doSmth();  
    return new CommonRepositoryFactory<>(em);
  }

  private static class CommonRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public CommonRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {
      super(em);
      this.em = em;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      JpaEntityInformation entityInformation = getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType());
      return new CommonRepositoryImpl(entityInformation, em);
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      return CommonRepositoryImpl.class;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: what spring version you are using?

Comment: ..why is  the `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` created via `new`? (is it unavoidable?)

Comment: Actually I am using Spring Boot 1.4, so spring version is 4.3.2

Comment: > why is the JpaRepositoryFactoryBean created via new
cause Spring Data project handles it

Answer (score 0):

Implement a setter in that class or one that extends from it.

Comment: Extend this class and include a setter in the extension